# How do I safely convert an char* to different types

Tags: c++, c++11, casting

I have a incoming char buffer from a different machine (an amplifier that I'm "talking" to using rs485) and I want to cast the data to different types like uint16_t, uint32_t etc.
I'm currently using `*(reinterpret_cast<T*>(buffer+offset))` in my code, and it's working, but I'm afraid that this won't be safe once I use a machine that uses a different endianess. Is there a better way?

I'm working on c++11

Comment: Do you mean that the memory buffer may be coming from a different machine?

Comment: `htons`, `ntohs`?

Comment: You need to go to the developer that makes the component that produces the buffer, demand the **documentation** of the data format, and proceed accordingly. If that developer is you, you still do the exact same thing.

Comment: @vipw Yes, I should've clarified

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yes! that might be it. I guess the answer would be `noths(*(reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(buffer+offset)))` right?

Comment: Yes. Just make sure the source places it in network order too.

Comment: ... which is essentially what @n.m. is saying.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Wouldn't that be a violation of the strict aliasing rule?

Comment: @interjay aliasing via `char` is ok

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Aliasing any type `T` as `char` is OK. But aliasing `char`s as `T` is not. It goes only one way.

Comment: @interjay - Yes, most useful applications would likely use something that is UB from the standard's perspective. Lucky for them, there are guarantors beyond the C++ standard itself. Vendors define things the standard leaves undefined.

Comment: If OP is on little-endian machine and it's working now, it means that the byte order is already wrong at the communication level and `htons` won't help.